# Parallel Jobs in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, winforms, parallel-processing

I have a windows form application which uses a local SQL server on LAN. Some parts of this windows application includes running some SELECT queries on SQL, but every time i run a query through my c# windows application, it will freeze and wait for DB answer. what i want to know is how can i have a system to handle my DB job on a different CPU or etc... so my application won't freeze and wait for DB to reply, something like the google search engine where you type and get results simultaneously.

I'm really new to C# so please answer in a way I can understand.

Comment: there might be some benefit in showing us the code that connects to the db and the way you are querying for records.  without this we can only guess what you are doing wrong

Comment: What kind of select query are you doing that makes a computer to freeze. You either have issues with your code or your hardware performance

Comment: when i say freeze, i only mean that i can no longer press buttons.

Comment: @Vahid.M post your code. Although I suspect you should look for eg `ExecuteScalarAsync` and async/await, not parallel execution. There are a lot of duplicate questions. If you want help with your code, post it here

Answer (score 1):

Application get freeze since you are executing your DB calls from UI thread. You should run time-consuming code (DB calls, API calls etc) in a separate thread.

You can use Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await to achieve this.

Please read more on [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and [this tutorial](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/) will explain how to update UI when using Async-Await.

```
private async void ButtonClickHandlerAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        you can do your time-consuming tasks here;
    });
}
```

If you can post a sample code segment with your question, it will help to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: This is a good TL;DR of the question.

Comment: The tutorials show that you don't need `Task.Run` to execute a query asynchronously